# Limitation on sending data in SOA client

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, integration, soa, webservice-client

I have an application that retrieves data from a specific database and through a SOA client sends this data to the integration, I have several threads sending instantiating this client and sending this data in parallel. However, the amount of submissions is being limited to 1,000,000 per hour, so when I reach this limit, I will have to send the registrations in the next submission and so on. What implementation/technology can I use to ensure that all records are submitted?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like any persistent queue would be helpful here. I'd make it so that all the request behave the same, that is the server would only reply with a place to get the data (or the client would give a callback to where the data should be sent) and all the server will do on request would be to queue the request and return the next step. It can then have separate process read from the queue and process the requests at whichever way makes sense